# Jupyter Notebook C user input

Tags: c, jupyter-notebook, scanf

I am trying to some simple C code in a Jupyter notebook that accepts user input. An example of this is:

```
// Problem 7.4
// Write a program that calculates the average of an array of 10 floating-point values.

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        float values[10] = {0};

        for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            printf("Enter the %ith number: ", i);
            scanf("%f", &values[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

and the output is simply:

```
Enter the 0th number: 
Enter the 1th number: 
Enter the 2th number: 
Enter the 3th number: 
Enter the 4th number: 
Enter the 5th number: 
Enter the 6th number: 
Enter the 7th number: 
Enter the 8th number: 
Enter the 9th number: 
Enter the 10th number:
```

without ever giving a chance for user input. Is there a way to do this the Jupyter C kernel?

Comment: Aside: please correct the loop `for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )` to be `for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )` because the maximum allowed array index is `9`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I edited it when I copied from Jupyter and into a .c file. MATLAB indexing always gets me lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this the Jupyter C kernel?

Not right now. Seems like they are still working on it though.

See: https://github.com/brendan-rius/jupyter-c-kernel/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
https://github.com/XaverKlemenschits/jupyter-c-kernel

It says:
Command line input via scanf and getchar